# HttpURLConnection java range

Tags: java, range, httpurlconnection

I use '`HttpURLConnection`' in Java with the "`Range`" property to download a segment of a file, i set the range `60000-560000`, and i can read `500000` bytes data,  which is `560000-60000`. But when the range is `0-60000`, i can read 60001 bytes data, which does not equal `60000-0`.

Why? Can anybody give me some explanation?

Comment: It may depend on the server. Different servers handle byte range requests differently. Some don't handle it them at all.

Comment: Can you grab the header from the response to get us an idea which server you are using.

Comment: Actually from glancing at the spec's examples, the 0-60000 SHOULD give you 60001 bytes. You should be able to read 500,001 bytes with your other range. So your issues is actually inverted.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour. Both bounds of the range are inclusive. From [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.1):

> The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset
> of the first byte in a range.  The last-byte-pos value gives the
> byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, the byte
> positions specified are inclusive.  Byte offsets start at zero.

> Examples of byte-ranges-specifier values:

> o  The first 500 bytes (byte offsets 0-499, inclusive):

> ```
>    bytes=0-499
> ```

> o  The second 500 bytes (byte offsets 500-999, inclusive):

> ```
>    bytes=500-999
> ```